# Find files in nested directories using REGEX

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

So I have a folder with this structure.

```
topperlayer
    ├── layerone
    │   └── testfile
    └── layertwo
```

Like `layerone` and `layertwo`, there can be many directories, even subdirs under the layers.

One of layer or the subdirs of the layer has a file `testfile`.

Is it possible to get where the `testfile` is located using REGEX?

Something like -

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(ls topperlayer/<REGEX>/testfile)
```

I can do an `os.walk` on every directories and subdirs to find the file in python. But want to do this in the shell with **REGEX**.

Any help or directions would be really appreciated.

**PS - I have no knowledge about REGEX.**

Comment: Why do you need a "REGEX"? `find . -type f -name testfile` should be enough.

Comment: @muru but the path goes into SumoLogic config file, I just need to specify a `topperlayer/<REGEX>/thefile` I need, so that the tool can get the file and push it to the server.

Comment: @roaima, I'm using bash.

Comment: You're not using bash or any other shell if you're specifying a path in a config file to some app. I don't see how this is a shell scripting problem at all. It depends on what regex flavour the application supports and how it interprets it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specify the path to the `testfile` file in a configuration file (as you mention in comments), you must first know where it's located.

Two solutions for that:

1. ```
   find topperlayer -type f -name testfile
   ```

   This would search the directory `topperlayer` and all subdirectories fore the regular file called `testfile`.  The pathname of each found file is then printed.
2. ```
   shopt -s globstar
   printf '%s\n' topperlayer/**/testfile
   ```

   This would first enable the `globstar` shell option in `bash`.  This allows you to use the `**` globbing pattern which works similarly to `*` but matches "recursively".  The `printf` will then print each name matching the given globbing pattern.

Both alternatives above would print the pathnames of *every* `testfile` under `topperlayer`.

Once you have located the appropriate pathname of the file, add it to your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

`find` is you friend.

```
find topperlayer -path 'glob/testfile'
```

Replace glob with a pattern (not a regex) e.g. `start*middle*end`

If you need regex, then use option `-regex`

```
find topperlayer -regex 'regex/testfile'
```